# How can I create a stored procedure in mySQL without declaring all the parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures

Probably a simple answer to this one but I can't find the answer online :(

I am currently migrating to MySQL database but I am having problems transfering my stored procedures from my dataset in Visual Studio. The SQL query in my dataset did not force me to name all the parameters however, MySQL gives a syntax error when I use ? instead of naming and declaring every single parameter.

SQL query in dataset of Visual Studio:

```
UPDATE       tblConfigurations
SET                DEUnit_ID_UnitName = ?, DEUnit_ID_UnitType = ?, DEUnit_ID_UnitLevel = ?, DEUnit_Aut_NumberOfMastercards = ?, DEUnit_Aut_MasterCardId1 = ?, DEUnit_Aut_MasterCardId2 = ?, 
                         DEUnit_Aut_MasterCardId3 = ?, DEUnit_Aut_MasterCardId4 = ?, DEUnit_Aut_MasterCardId5 = ?, DEUnit_Aut_MasterCardId6 = ?, DEUnit_Aut_MasterCardId7 = ?, DEUnit_Aut_MasterCardId8 = ?, 
                         DEUnit_Lck_SeperatedAntennas = ?, DEUnit_AF_SilentAlarmActivation = ?, DEUnit_AF_AlarmInputConnection = ?, DEUnit_NW_Address = ?, DEUnit_KD_KeyboardOrientation = ?, 
                         DEUnit_KD_SpecialAcousticConfirmation = ?, DEUnit_KD_KeyClickSound = ?, DEUnit_KD_LedColors = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue1 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue2 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue4 = ?, 
                         DEUnit_ReservedValue7 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue8 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue9 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue10 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue11 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue12 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue13 = ?,
                          DEUnit_ReservedValue14 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue15 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue22 = ?, DEUnit_ReservedValue27 = ?
WHERE        (config_ID = ?)
```

Comment: Why not give them names? It's better than question marks.

Comment: I agree, it would be better. However I did want to go through each and every stored procedure and update it with names because I have over 100 SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `?` placeholders only if you use the PREPARE and EXECUTE syntax. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html for details.

But even if you do use PREPARE & EXECUTE, you would still have to name the variables as you pass them to EXECUTE.

In a stored procedure, you can use variables instead of using placeholders.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE citycount (IN country CHAR(3), OUT cities INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cities FROM world.city
  WHERE CountryCode = country;
END
```

In that example, `country` is a procedure input parameter. You can use it directly in an SQL statement (in this case SELECT, but it works for UPDATE too).

Make sure your parameter names are not the same as any column in the table you query, because that creates an ambiguity.